# C# MySQL Connection problems

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm now using Visual Studio 2008 Pro Edition. I installed [Connector/Net 5.2](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html) with Visual Studio integration. I restarted Visual Studio, and MySQL database now appears in the list of data providers. I entered my database information, and clicked "Test Connection" and it succeeds, but when I try to close the Add Connection dialog, I get an error:

```
Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.
```

Have I missed a step in setting this up?

Comment: have you restart your PC after MySQL client installation ?

Comment: darn... I'm going to try that

Comment: restarted the application, and installed the SP1 for Visual Studio. Still get the same problem

Comment: Not really, just bypassed the error by not using the visual DB tools for integration, and then switched to the C# Express Edition, which doesn't support this at all.

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem with the CTP version of VS and the solution was [this](http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2007/03/orcas-march-ctp-on-vista-database.html).

Even if you are running a RTM version, it might be worth checking your config file.

Comment: I'm not using Vista, I'm using XP. And I couldn't find the line they said to comment out in the machine.config file.